# Как сделать, чтоб цикл работал ровно 3 минуты?

Tags: c

Цикл должен отработать ровно 3 минуты, а затем быть автоматически прерванным.

Comment: Зависит от контекста - например, хотите ли вы таким образом сделать задержку, или прервать поиск оптимального решения - тем, до которого добрались за 3 минуты; необходимой точностью - например, досчитывать ли в последнем случае итерацию, которая переходит границу 3 минут, или ее надо срочно обрывать... Словом, по возможности, уточните задачу.

Comment: Зависит от того, как долго работает итерация цикла. Если она работает 2 минуты, то может получиться либо 1 итерация за 2 минуты, либо 2 за 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запоминайте время перед входом в цикл, а потом проверяйте на каждой итерации, сколько прошло времени с начала.

```
#include <time.h>

...
time_t start_time = time(NULL);
while (difftime(time(NULL), start_time) < 3 * 60) {
  <do something>
}
```

Comment: При формировании временных интервалов лучше опираться на `clock`, чем на `time` - функция `time` возвращает текущее календарное время, которое может быть изменено во время выполнения программы. Также необходимо заметить, что формат представления времени типом `time_t` не определен (это не обязательно секунды от известной даты) и для определения разности двух времен необходимо использовать функцию `difftime`.

Comment: @KonstantinLes, спасибо за уточнения! Про то, что time может возвращать не секунды не знал (в Linux-овом man-е написано, что именно секунды).

Comment: С другой стороны clock() тоже не лишен недостатков: 1) если процессор загружен другими программами, то он может идти медленнее часов 2) если в нашей программе несколько тредов, то он будет идти значительно быстрее часов

Comment: Да, действительно (до сих пор считал, что `clock` возвращает общее процессорное время). Тогда только на основе `time` и `difftime` в надежде, что время не изменится, или пользоваться сервисами операционной системы (или C++11 - там есть нужные таймеры).

Comment: сорри что так поздно спрашиваю, но где можно почитать про зависимость скорости `clock` от загруженности процессора и кол-ва тредов???

Answer (score 3):

Минимальный компилируемый пример цикла, работающего 3 секунды:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  int sec = 0;
  clock_t start = clock(), diff;
  do {
    diff = clock() - start;
    sec = diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  } while (sec < 3); /*для получения минут умножьте 3 на 60*/

  printf("Time taken %d seconds\n", sec);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: aleks.andr, только не 3 секунды, а 3 минуты, так что поправьте там ответ измените на "sec < 3 * 60"